# Connect react native mobile app to AWS websocket API

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, websocket, expo, aws-api-gateway

I am building a card game on mobile, with React Native and Expo. I would like to allow real-time updates during a game and I thought about using AWS Gateway's websocket API.

I created the API on AWS Gateway and the following code in React Native to connect to it:

```
connectToWebSocket = (onConnected) => {
    const socket = new WebSocket("wss://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production");

    socket.addEventListener("open", (e) => {
        onConnected();
    });
    socket.addEventListener("close", (e) => console.log("WebSocket is closed"));
    socket.addEventListener("error", (e) => console.error(e));

};
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error `Event {isTrusted: false}` and does not connect.

It seems that all the available examples online are about building a web app that connects to AWS Gateway, but not for a mobile app. I've been reading tutorials for hours now and am completely stuck.

Is there any way for me to use AWS Gateway's websocket API for my project?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The very first thing is that my Websocket API was not deployed.
On the `Routes` panel, I had to go to `Actions>Deploy API`

The second thing is that my route Integration types were Lambdas, but I had not switched the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` flag on. Because of that, no `event` was sent to my lambda and the code was failing.

Once I had fixed both of those, I could connect without a problem :)